# I have a problem with migration in Entity Framework Core

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

I tried to create a database with EF Core but I got this error:

> No migrations configuration type was found in the assembly 'WebApplication8'. (In Visual Studio you can use the Enable-Migrations command from Package Manager Console to add a migrations configuration)

Then I tried enabling migrations:

```
Enable-Migrations
```

but now I get this error:

> No context type was found in the assembly 'WebApplication8'

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using MyEshop.Models;

namespace MyEshop.Data
{
    public class MyEshopContext : DbContext
    {
        public MyEshopContext(DbContextOptions<MyEshopContext> options) : base(options)
        {
        }

        public DbSet<Category> Categories { get; set; }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            #region Seed Data Category
            modelBuilder.Entity<Category>().HasData(new Category()
            {
                Id = 1,
                Name = "Asp.Net Core",
                Description = "Asp.Net Core 3"
            },
            new Category()
            );
            #endregion

            base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: make sure you have set the correct project as the startup project. and you have to choose the default project the one which has the DBContext class